# Punctuation issues in the privacy policy page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privacy

In the [Stack Exchange, Inc. Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) page, there are two punctuation issues. In front of the "This privacy policy" the space is missing.

In the first paragraph:

> ... and as such are committed to your privacy.This privacy policy ...

and in the third paragraph:

> ... where Stack Overflow operates.This privacy policy has been ...

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Punctuation issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (rev `2018.5.22.30470`).